# Limiting xfer'd bytes per visitor with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, rate-limiting

From time to time, I'm visited by "leechers" downloading an entire site (~2 GB) within a few hours, while the average visitor stays far below 50 MB. I'd like to setup a "byte-limit" per visitor (e.g. allowing max 100 MB per day and visitor).

I've tried [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/), which comes pretty close to my goal. Unfortunately I've managed only to establish a quote *per VHost* – i.e. if the quota was hit, the entire VHost becomes blocked. *mod_cband* also can manage quotas per remote IP – but for that I'd need to know those IPs in advance, which I do not.

I've also looked into [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442), which I already use in slightly different context. But this only lets me limit the number of requests, and doesn't take the "volume" (bytes transferred) into account.

Are there any "ready-to-use" solutions available? If I've missed something with *mod_cband*, hints are welcome as well. If a solution cannot be bound to a VHost (but would apply server-wide), that would be acceptable as well (though per VHost is preferred).

Note I do ***not*** want to [limit the bandwith](https://serverfault.com/q/246818/145213) (i.e. speed), neither [limit simultaneously requests per IP](https://serverfault.com/q/252555/145213); this is not about bandwidth but against "copy-cats".

**Edit:** I've just found [Apache::Quota](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Apache-Quota-0.04/lib/Apache/Quota.pm) which seems to do pretty much what I want. But it a) requires to have `mod_perl` running (I'm not that familiar with Perl coding), and b) seems unmaintained (latest version is v0.04, dating back to 3/2007, and was intended for Apache 1.3 if I got that correctly).

**Edit2:** Solutions based on [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/) or [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) are welcome, too. So far, all I've found in this context was speed throtteling or limiting the amount of connections per remote IP, which is not what I'm after.

**Edit3:** Though I already found a solution for the underlying issue (see my answer below), I'm still interested in a solution to establish a "transfer quota per visitor and time", as described in my question – as my solution cannot be applied everywhere (see the "assumptions" described there).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second ?

Comment: @JakovSosic nope I don't want to rate-limit "requests per second", but "data throughput per day". Actually I've checked with that question before (which is how I came to know about `mod_cband`). That question doesn't focus on the ***per visitor*** part, but is rather *per server/VHost*. (Apart from that, I'd VTC that for "too broad" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I tapped into the [XY trap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154) – and completely missed a piece of software I'm already using for other things: **[Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/)**. As the original intention was to stop leachers, that's easily done with a matching jail.

#### Assumptions

- the site contains informational pages linking to local resources (e.g. ZIP or PDF files), which can easily be matched from the QUERY_STRING
- "normal" visitors are browsing the pages, but only pick a few "resources"
- a "leecher", processing all pages, would naturally hit more "resource files" in a short time frame than a "normal visitor" in all of the day. In my case, 50 hits/d would already be plenty for a "normal visitor".

#### Fail2Ban filter

The Fail2Ban filter makes use of those assumptions, matching only resources. This can be via file extensions (example above: `.pdf` or `.zip`), or by a path (e.g. with all resources being located in `/downloads` – but should make sure to not match the "normal pages". So here's an example filter (to be placed in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-leecher.conf`):

```
[Definition]
# Match all our resources below /downloads:
failregex = ^ -.*"(GET|POST) /download.*"

# Alternatively, match all PDF/ZIP files
# failregex = ^ -.*"(GET|POST) .*\.(zip|pdf)"
```

(I've put the ZIP/PDF variant in as comment; you should only have one `failregex` in your filter file)

#### Fail2Ban Jail

Now for the corresponding jail, configured in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`:

```
[apache-leecher]
# download no more than 100 files per hour, or get blocked for 6h (21600s)
enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-leecher
logpath = /var/log/httpd/access_log
maxretry = 100
findtime = 3600
bantime  = 21600
```

Seems to work (already caught 2 candidates), but might need some fine-tuning. Anyone in a similar situation should be able to easily adapt the above to match the site.

Comment: This is isn't working for me for some reason. I set it to maxretry = 2 to test it out, and it allows me to keep downloading more than 2. I changed the regex to the correct directory.

Comment: Make sure the path to your log file matches, and the `failregex` matches as well. Check the log for entries matching the `failregex` – and also check the status of `fail2ban`. Fail2ban sometimes reacts with a little delay, too.